# html img percentage looks awkward in ipad

Tags: html, css, image

I need to display image with height and width set to some percentage like img src="image.jpg" width="75%" height="75%" . this works fine in all PC's browsers. when i open the same webpage in ipad or in other tablets browser, the image looks so awkward. the width will be very less and height of image is scaled throughout height of tablet.

sample url is here:
http://www.stringroot.com/postid/01a32j1a7

am i doing anything wrong in my css or setting height and width of an image?.

should i go ahead using some formula to convert percentage to pixels?.

I am newbie to css and frontend . any pointers will help me a lot.

I want to just display 50% of entire image, and on click i will display full image.

Comment: Do you have the meta tag included for mobile and tablet devices ?

Comment: Dam, this has so many problems with it i don't even want to start lol

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the image as a background of an element, the widths you're setting (which should be set in css not as attributes) will change the size of the image, not hide some of it.

```
//Markup
<div style="background: url(/site_media/rao_soft2771/ileana7a_.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;">
</div>

.fancybox {
    height: 75%;
    width: 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and then remove the image from .fancybox

That should be enough to get you started :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I dont want to hardcode photo path in css, as the photo is dynamic and varies with postid. with your css suggestion , photos are lookin better in ipad. but still the photo needs to look better in ipad, it looks like photo is scaled throughout device height.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve your problem, I'll put a TL;DR; answer here, and my 2cents below.

Method 1:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="img_wrapper">
      <a href=""><img src="image.jpg" class="visible_img"/></a>
   </div>
   <img src="image.jpg" class="invisible_img"/>
</div>
```

(Both image use the same img src)

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img_wrapper{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

img.invisible_img{
    visibility: hidden;
}

img.visible_img{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Method 2 use CSS scale():
Simply give your original img a class:

**HTML**

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="resized_img"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.resized_img{
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
       -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.75);
         -o-transform: scale(0.75);
            transform: scale(0.75);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
         -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
            transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

For both method I provide though, the container (the li) will still take up the full image's width and height.

Some thoughts on your problem:

Percentage width and height are calculated using the width and height of the image's container. In your example link, the image's container (the li) has a width of 600px, and *no height value is given*. On pc browser, your *width="75%" height="75%"* is rendered as width = 75% of 600px (which is 450px), height = 75% of an undefined value (which the browser understood as height: auto;). Please note that your image is 1440x900, so 450px is not 75% of the image's original width.

On your particular mobile browser (the ipad), it is not as flexible as a pc browser and understood your height = 75% as 75% of some maximum possible height its container can reach (which is an enormous height). That is why your image is skewed.

Normally, you're encouraged to display the image according to the screen size (and thus the container's size), and not as a portion of its original size. Because the each user's screen is different, for some user your image may appear too small or too large.

Another problem is the image's size. Your image is resized on client-side, that means the server is still sending the full image to the user. If the user doesn't click on the image to view it in full size, you have just wasted ~2 times more bandwidth than needed to serve a thumbnail. If you make a picture gallery of 20 images, and the user only view one, the wasted bandwidth is multiplied 19 times. Normally the image thumbnail and the full image should be 2 different files of different sizes, provided by the server only when needed. (and if you use this approach you will be able to solve your problem in a clean & effective way too).